# Undefined control sequence on legitimate LyX macro

Tags: macros, errors, lyx

I'm trying to define a LyX macro, Insert -> Math -> Macro on the menus. It's a very simple macro. Source code under View -> View Source:

```
\global\long\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}
```

The file compiles nicely if I don't use the macro. However, once I put a  `\Z`   inside a Math formula and try to compile, it gives me an *Undefined control sequence* with the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\Z ->\mathbb 
             {Z}
l.32 d$\Z
         $
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Now, the most peculiar thing is that I have used this exact same macro on other files, where it works perfectly.

In case it might be of any help, I'm using the *article* document class on LyX 2.0.0. Could it be that the document encoding or document class make a difference? Or maybe the document language setting?

[A complete log of the LaTeX errors is available at this link](http://math.huji.ac.il/~shlomiag/compilation%20errors.txt).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you report the complete error message? I suspect that the undefined control sequence is `\mathbb`. Do you load the `amssymb` package?

Comment: Also (and unrelated) `\global` and `\long` are not doing anything for a top level definition with no arguments.

Comment: Thanks @egreg and David. I've modified the question to include a link to the complete error log. I don't know whether I've loaded the `amssymb` package or not. I'm working on LyX, and I don't know how to check that? However, if I don't use the macro and instead I just type `\mathbb Z` inside a LyX formula it works fine, and compiles with no problem.

Comment: The error message says that `\mathbb` is the undefined command, as I suspected. Neither `amssymb` nor `amsfonts` that would define it are loaded, according to the log. I really don't know how to coerce LyX into loading `amssymb`, but *this* is the thing you should try to do.

Comment: To tell LyX to load `amssymb` one can do either 1) Document --> Settings --> Math options, and check *Use AMS Package*, or 2) Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, and add `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: Does what @TorbjørnT. suggests fix the issue?

Comment: @Torbjørn T., thanks! The _Use AMS math package automatically_ was already checked, and so that didn't solve the issue. However, when adding the '\usepackage{amssymb}' to the preamble as you've suggested it was instantly fixed. Thanks a lot!   :-)

Comment: @ShlomiA You misunderstood slightly, *Use AMS automatically* will not force LyX to load AMS packages, it will only do so if you add e.g. an AMS environment (Insert --> Math --> ...), so to force loading, *uncheck* the automatic choice, and check *Use AMS Package*, just below. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As egreg mentions in a comment, the reason you get the error is that neither the `amsfonts` nor `amssymb` package, where `\mathbb` is defined, is loaded. To force LyX to add one of these you can do one of two things:

1. Go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and add there either

   ```
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   ```

   or

   ```
   \usepackage{amsfonts}
   ```
2. Go to Document --> Settings --> Math options. Uncheck *Use AMS math package automatically* and check *Use AMS math package*, as in the screenshot below. LyX will now have added

   ```
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   ```

   to the document preamble.

   The first of these, the automatic one, adds these packages only if you use some of their features through the LyX GUI. E.g. if you do Insert --> Math --> AMS Align, the `amsmath` package will be added, and if you e.g. add some text with Blackboard bold via the math font button on the toolbar -- [image] -- then `amssymb` will be added.

   [image]

Comment: Why should LyX use `\global\long\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}` is beyond my understanding.